# Get menu names and same depth level menu names

Tags: breadcrumb

Let's say I have a menu like this..

```
Home
Food
 -- rice
 -- apple
 -- sushi
Sports
 -- soccer
 -- basketball
 -- football
Color
 -- red
 -- blue
 -- black
```

When I am on sushi page, I need to get like this.. (like breadcrumb)

```
Food > sushi
```

Current menu name and upper level menu name (if there is)

And when I put mouse on sushi, it will be a dropdown menu showing same depth level menus "rice, apple, sushi"

I may be able to working on the dropdown script but I don't know how to get these menu names and links.

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is a little vague but it should get you started.  It seems like you need to:

1. Check if the page has a parent `<?php if($post->post_parent) ?>`
2. Something like `<?php echo $post->post_parent; ?>`
3. Something like `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>`
4. Something like the code below, then apply your solution for turning it into a dropdown.

There is more info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

```
<?php
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't know why.. It doesn't work for me.
Do I have to make pages hierarchy? parents pages and child pages? it doesn't showing. anyway thanks for your time and let me know if you have any idea.